# How could I call the "pieces" of a non simply connected domain?

Tags: general-topology, terminology

I am writing an article and I would like to use the formal terminology but I am not aware if there is some. 
For instance assume that $\Omega$ is a non-simply-connected domain, for instance let $\Omega:=[0,10]\bigcup[20,30]$ . Is there any name I can give the simply connected part of this non-simply connected domain?  I could simply rename them as $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$ but in my particular case it would render things complicated because I would like to work in general terms.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Depending on what you want to convey, "(connected) components" or "path (connected) components" might fit the bill. But since you emphasize "simply connected" I don't know what you'd want to do with, say, an annulus.

Comment: I am not really into this topological concepts, but since my domain is in the real line (univariate) I suppose it does not change anything, or I am wrong?

Comment: If your domain is the real line then there is no point in using the term "simply connected", since it is the same as "connected".  And in that case, the word you want is "components", as Mark says.

Comment: Thank you both. You might want to add it as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: In the case of the real line, the term "interval" is also popular, though some refrain from using it for points or unbounded components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only care about subsets of $\mathbb R$, and if $[0,1)\cup\{2\}\cup[5,\infty)$ has three "pieces", then I would just call the pieces "components". If you wouldn't want to count $\{2\}$ because it has length $0$, then you could call the other two "'proper' intervals" (perhaps alternately "'genuine' intervals"), but some reserve that for bounded intervals only.

---

In topology, there are many related concepts: A topological (sub)space could be [connected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space#Formal_definition), [path-connected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space#Path_connectedness), [arc-connected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space#Arc_connectedness), [simply-connected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simply_connected_space). It turns out that for subspaces of $\mathbb R$, all of those concepts coincide. For most of these, we can talk about [components](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Component_(Topology)) that are connected in that way. But we would not speak of "simply-connected components" since simply-connected means something like "has no holes", and which are the no-holes pieces of an [annulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annulus_(mathematics))?